# Javascript anonymous function expression

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Good morning in my timezone

I saw the following snippet of code

```
var Tabs = (function () {
                  function Tabs() {}

                  Tabs.annotations = [
                    new ComponentMetadata({...}),
                  ];

                  return Tabs;
                })
```

What is the difference between declare the anonymous function inside the parenthesis or without parenthesis like this way

```
var Tabs = function () {
                      function Tabs() {}

                      Tabs.annotations = [
                        new ComponentMetadata({...}),
                      ];

                      return Tabs;
                    }
```

I use console and the print was the same

Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Comment: No difference, if it really ends with `})`. If it ended in `})()`, it would be an IIFE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expression can be followed by parentheses. 
For example the following code causes syntax error because the function definition can not be followed by parentheses.

```
function(){
    //code
}();
```

However you can turn function definition into function expression by wrapping with parentheses:

```
(function(){
    //code
})();
```

Now that became a immediately invoked anonymous function :).